# What happens if non-deterministic contract passes consensus quota, and the remain nodes have different results in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, consensus

In Hyperledger Fabric, chaincode can contain non-deterministic funcitons, and necessary consensus percentage can be customized. 
What happens if chain code is non-deterministic and the output is different in some nodes, but consensus was passed.

How syncronizing is archived ?
Can new node joined this channel have same transaction history?

Answer (score 0):

Since the endorsement passed it will be commited then syncronized by gossip with all nodes.

The nodes on committing(VSCC) only verify the signature and if the minimun necessary set of endorsers was reached.

For example if you require 2 out of 3 Orgs to agree, when you have the minimum necessary(2) agreeing it will be commited without the need of the third org.